# Flask: How to redirect to the post view after it has been submitted?

Tags: python, flask

I have this so far:

```
@app.route('/view/<postname>')
def view_post(postname):

    posts_folder = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'content', 'posts'))
    filename = safe_join(posts_folder, postname)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
        html = markdown.markdown(content)
        return render_template("view.html",html=html,postname=postname)

class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    postTitle = StringField('postTitle', validators=[DataRequired()])
    postText = TextAreaField('postText',validators=[DataRequired()])

@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():
    postname = request.form["postTitle"]
    print postname
    posts_folder = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'content', 'posts'))
    filename = safe_join(posts_folder, postname)
    with open(filename,'wb') as f:
        f.write(request.form['postText'])
    while True:
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            return redirect(url_for(view_post(postname)))
            break
        else:
            pass
```

As you can see, I have a form, which, when it submits, directs to my /submit route. This route creates a new post file and writes the content of the post to it. Then, it should redirect to the view post route so that it can see the recently created post. It needs to wait until the post is finished writing to the file before it tries to load this route. You can see that I attempted to handle for this in the while True loop. However, right now the error shows:

```
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint u'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n&lt;p&gt;b&lt;/p&gt;\n<br>\n<a href="/edit/a">\n        a\n    </a>\n\n<html>'. Did you mean 'edit_post' instead?
```

as if the url_for(view_post(postname)) is somehow trying to view raw html. When I print postname however, it prints the contents of the postTitle object which is the filename i intend to save and re-route to.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing :

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():
    postname = request.form["postTitle"]
    print postname
    posts_folder = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'content', 'posts'))
    filename = safe_join(posts_folder, postname)
    with open(filename,'wb') as f:
        f.write(request.form['postText'])
    return redirect(url_for('view_post', postname=postname))
```

which works! The problem is it doesn't wait until the file loads which could be a problem for really big files. But it seems like they'd have to be pretty big. Though Ill leave this question up in case someone has an actual answer (assuming that the file upload does take a non-trivial amount of time). Also my error was happening because I forgot the quotes around 'view_post' in the url_for redirect at the bottom